# loopj jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am using plugin for Jquery that I found at http://loopj.com/2009/04/25/jquery-plugin-tokenizing-autocomplete-text-entry/ This plugin allows multiple items to be select into a text field such as facebook and gmail when composing a message. I was really impressed but ran into one problem. For the life of me I could no figure out how to properly get the results in the text input field. I also had no idea on how to grab any results from settings.jsonContainer as the website indicated. Can anyone explain to me how this is done? Thanks

Comment: Sorry to say, but why did you rollback the removal of `J` tag? This is not the J language. Click the `J` tag and see. How is your own question related? As to your question, you will maybe get more response if you add more information about the plugin (links? docs?) and show your own efforts (the code examples/attempts and so on).

Comment: I added the J tag because I wanted "loopj"  as a tag.  I couldn't create one as I didn't have enough reputation. Anyhow, going to add more information to my question.

Comment: OK, but you're now the only one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loopj :)

Answer (score 0):

OK figured out that problem or actually found the solution. Just have to use "document.getelementById('textfield id').value". It returns the ids enter from the json however, I have one more issue before I have it working exactly to my liking. If an item has already been selected and in the textfield, the same item shows up in the popup selection anyways.  Scince there will be user names going into this textfield I do not want any of them to be availble in the popup.

Thanks